# Jquery remove item above specific class

Tags: jquery

I have 3 pages. Each one has the structure below, but has a unique class: "**module a**" or "**module b**" or "**module c**".

How can I remove using JQuery **.body** and **.subtitle** only when class is "**module b**" below.

**Page 1:**

```
<section class="main">
   <h1 class="subtitle" />
   <div class="body" />
   <div class="module a" />
</section>
```

**Page 2:**

```
<section class="main">
   <h1 class="subtitle" />
   <div class="body" />
   <div class="module b" />
</section>
```

**Page 3:**

```
<section class="main">
   <h1 class="subtitle" />
   <div class="body" />
   <div class="module c" />
</section>
```

Comment: It should be either class `module_b` or something like div with classes `module` and `b`(2 classes).

Comment: You only want to remove subtitle and body? or module b too?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
$('.module.b')
  .prevAll('.body,.subtitle')
  .remove()
```

Comment: +1 `prevAll` is definitely better than going over all siblings.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below,

```
$('.module.b').siblings('.body, .subtitle').remove();
```

or

```
$('.module.b').parent().find('.body, .subtitle').remove();
```

Note above `.module.b` means an element with class both `module` and `b`(2 classes).

If `module b` what you meant is 1 class rule then it should be like `module_b` in that case replace above `.module.b` with `module_b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.module.b').parent('.main').find('.subtitle, .body').remove();
```

That should do the trick I think!

Hope that helps :)